# Error Python int too large to convert to C long solved by appending rb tag. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to open a [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) file like so

`file = open('hello.pcap')`

and it's returning a `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` error.

After looking around on the web, I found a solution of adding  `rb` like so

`file = open('hello.pcap' , 'rb')`

and now it works perfectly.

Two Questions:

What is the error referring to?

And I understand that `r` means READ only and `b` means open in binary, but why do I need to append the `rb` file in this specific scenario?

I am following along with [this tutorial](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/) and it doesn't appear that the guy is using the `rb` tag.

Comment: Do you use  Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MikeMüller  am using Python 2.7

Comment: That's a really weird error message to get if you're running into a text/binary issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary. While you can skip the `rb` ( but should not) on Unix systems, you need to have it on Windows. Likely that the tutorial was written on a Unix system.

Answer (score 1):

`pcap`s are binary, not text files. You need to open binary files as binary.